# how to dynamically update a workbook name in excel using vba?

Tags: vba, excel

I’m trying to dynamically update a workbook name in a formula in excel to bring through data from a continually changing source file.

So far I have been getting by with using an indirect formula, but now I have a huge workbook with around 216,000 cells to populate and I don’t think indirect is the most efficient way to do this.

I want to use VBA instead but I have no experience with this. From doing some googling I have found a few things but I’m not sure how to implement my specific needs into the code.

so far 've come up with this:

```
Sub replace()

Dim cell As Range

cell.Formula = replace(cell.Formula, "OfficeSupplies.csv", 
"OfficeSupplies2.csv")


Range("a1:d8").Value


Next

End Sub
```

However, when I try to execute it, it doesn't work at all.

Comment: Wouldn’t it be faster/easier if you updated connection in Excel UI?

Comment: Does ctrl + F to do find and replace cause a pop-up file dialog?

Comment: @DisplayName Good idea. OP might not understand what you mean.

Comment: I don't think it is terribly inefficent to have the all the cells pointing to one cell where you update the required name. Depends what else you have going on in the workbook I suppose.

Comment: @QHarr thats the current set up i have with my indirect formulas and its slow as hell.

Comment: I suspect you have a lot of other formulas or conditional format etc going on or maybe I am just wrong! :-)

Comment: @DisplayName wouldn't doing that and then excel having to recalculate everything be incredibly slow?

Comment: @QHarr yh, there's like 216,000 index matches

Comment: @reef, Excel would be recalculating even if you changed  formulas programatically (i.e. with VBA). Try and see that (maybe with a smaller file...). You may also try as per my answer.

Comment: I assumed you could just concatenate with one cell value holding the filename. Are there a host of file names?

Comment: @DisplayName so whatever I do, I'm looking at a long processing time I guess. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: @QHarr instead of doing that my indirect- index-match just contains a reference to the cell that contains the file name. 

Thanks for the advice though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edited** to insert the handling of a specified range instead of `ActiveSheet` used range and to handle a sheet different to "Active" one

To answer the question, you could use a code like the following to replace in "Active" sheet used range:

```
Sub replace()
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Replace(What:="OfficeSupplies.csv", Replacement:="OfficeSupplies2.csv", LookAt:=xlPart)
End Sub
```

or you could explicitly refer to a sheet:

```
Sub replaceInSpecifiedSheet()
    Worksheets("MySheetName").UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Replace(What:="OfficeSupplies.csv", Replacement:="OfficeSupplies2.csv", LookAt:=xlPart) ' change "MySheetName" to your actual sheet name
End Sub
```

or you could want to change formulas in a given range:

```
Sub replaceInSpecifiedRangeOfSpecifiedSheet()
    Worksheets("MySheetName").Range("A5:B8").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Replace(What:="OfficeSupplies.csv", Replacement:="OfficeSupplies2.csv", LookAt:=xlPart) ' change "MySheetName" to your actual sheet name
End Sub
```

But changing a formula in 216k cells can be quite a time consuming activity

You may consider the opposite: change the name of the”continually changing source file”

You can do that without VBA of course

Should you be “forced” to or prefer use VBA then you could use ‘Name ... As‘ statement

```
Sub replace2()
    Dim FullNameToChange As String
    Dim HardCodedFullName As String

    FullNameToChange = "C:\ChangingName.xls"
    HardCodedFullName = "C:\HardCodedName.xls"
    If Dir(FullNameToChange) <> "" And Dir(HardCodedFullName) = "" Then Name FullNameToChange As HardCodedFullName
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. would I need to have 
   ' Dim FullNameToChange as string'
at the beginning and do those empty quotes need to contain anything?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I'm a vba newb so I wasn't too sure if i was missing something or not!

Comment: You have to Dim if you place “Option Explicit” at the beginning of your module. Otherwise all undeclared variables are implicitly assumed as of Variant type. In this case this latter would do, but it’s considered best practice to always explicitly declare all variables so I edited my code to reflect this. And empty quotes are to stay as they are since they are needed as reference of empty strings. If this answer solved your question please consider marking it as accepted. Thank you

Comment: do I need to set the range? ie. range ("a5:b8").value
I run it but it doesn't seem to change the formulas, so I'm not sure if I need to add something in that says to apply this code to a certain range of cells

Comment: @reef, what code of mine are you referring to: `Sub replace()` or `Sub replace2()`?

Comment: @reef, see edited answer to account for both a specified range and a sheet different then `ActiveSheet`

Comment: Sorry, sub replace 2.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
Cells.Replace "OfficeSupplies.csv", "OfficeSupplies2.csv", xlPart, , True
```